# Wordpress, Querying Default blog posts and getting custom post types only

Tags: php, wordpress

On my homepage I am bringing in some custom post types using this:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 4 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
etc....
```

This works fine.  But then I just want to bring in a list of blog posts with the default taxonomy. So I try this:

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=uncategorized' );?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

And it spits out all the custom post types, but not the one blog post I have (the hello world blog post).  I feel like I have done this before without any problems, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think cat it's used with category id, in that case would be query_posts('cat=1');
If you want to use the name try ('category_name=whatever');

Hope its useful
GL

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [wp_reset_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) some place after your first query and before the spot where you're trying to include that list?